# Intended of Load JQuery once function in other js file executed completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, async-await

I am fetching some data from the database and based on retrieved data HTML is being rendered on the browser. Once the HTML is being rendered then I want to apply JQuery on them. following is my code
fetch_items.js File

```
async function itemsWithAllDetails() {
    let responseData = await retrieveItems();
    let itemsWithSizes = await getSizes(responseData);
    let itemsWithImages = await getImages(itemsWithSizes);
    let itemsWithColors = await getColors(itemsWithImages);
    let filtered_items_sales = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'sales_section');
    renderItems(filtered_items_sales, "sales_section");
    let filtered_items_boys = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'BOYS');
    renderItems(filtered_items_boys, "boys_section");
    let filtered_items_girls = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'GIRLS');
    renderItems(filtered_items_girls, "girls_section");
    let filtered_items_bboys = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'BABY BOYS');
    renderItems(filtered_items_bboys, "baby_boy_section");
    let filtered_items_bgirls = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'BABY GIRLS');
    renderItems(filtered_items_bgirls, "baby_girl_section");
    let filtered_items_men = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'MEN');
    renderItems(filtered_items_men, "men_section");
    let filtered_items_women = filterItems(itemsWithColors, 'WOMEN');
    renderItems(filtered_items_women, "women_section");
}

itemsWithAllDetails();
```

JQuery File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button.increament").click(function () {
    let x = $(this).siblings("input").val();
    if (x == "") {
        x = 0;
    }
    x = parseInt(x);
    if (x >= 5) {
        alert("You can not order more than 5");
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings("input").val(x + 1);
    }
    
});

$("button.decreament").click(function () {
    let x = $(this).siblings("input").val()
    if (x >= 1) {
        $(this).siblings("input").val(parseInt(x) - parseInt(1));
    }
});
// Increment Decrement Buttons End Here
});
```

Why events are not working? What I am doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score -1):

i did it by excluding events from $(document).ready();
Then include them in another function and called it from itemsWithAllDetails function at the end.